# To the Lighthouse -- "Whitening before rain"

Tags: symbolism

From Virgina Woolf's To the Lighthouse:

> It was fringed with joy. The wheelbarrow, the lawnmower, the sound of poplar trees, **leaves whitening before rain**, rooks cawing brooms knocking, dresses rustling -

How do leaves "whiten before rain"? Is this something common to all plants?

Additionally, is a "rook" a type of raven, or what is a rook?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(bird)) is a rook. But honestly, your whole question sounds like it might be better off on [biology.se], unless there's some special literary significance to the "whitening before rain" thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Farmer's Almanac, the leaves of some deciduous trees do indeed curl upwards before storms, reacting to atmospheric changes.

> But does seeing the undersides of leaves really mean rain is on the
> way? In this case, our forebears were definitely onto something. **The
> leaves of deciduous trees, like maples and poplars, do often to turn
> upward before heavy rain. The leaves are actually reacting to the
> sudden increase in humidity that usually precedes a storm.** Leaves with
> soft stems can become limp in response to abrupt changes in humidity,
> allowing the wind to flip them over.
>
> <sub><sup>[FarmersAlmanac.com - Can Leaves Predict a Storm?](http://farmersalmanac.com/weather/2009/06/08/can-leaves-predict-a-storm/)</sup></sub>

From below they would appear to *whiten before the storm* or as the old adage puts it,

> *“When leaves show their undersides, be very sure rain betides.”*

---

As to the latter point, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHHwg6cV2lU) is a rook (in this case an American Rook). No special symbolism required.